# How to make only first name appear on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Some people appear only their first names while the others appear their full names when they like/comment on my status. For example, some people appear; Rose Dream liked/commented on your photo but some: Rose commented/liked your photo. Can I know the difference, please?

Answer (score 1):

Officially it's not possible (except in Indonesia). Only *Indonesian* people are allowed (because in Indonesia, some people just have a single name) to have single name on Facebook. But by changing the proxy settings and language settings you can do this.

Some *tricks* are given in following links, and it should work:

[How To Make Single Name Account On Facebook](http://www.safetricks.com/2012/10/Make-Facebook-Account-With-Single-Name.html)

[First Name Visible On Facebook](http://www.techaroid.com/2014/02/trick-only-first-name-visible-on.html)

[Hide Last Name on Facebook](http://www.cryptlife.com/internet/social/how-to-hide-last-name-on-facebook)